# Migrate from beta version to Standard Edition

Tags: 2010

We have an installation of SharePoint 2010 beta that was long forgotten until today. There is a publishing site on that installation and now we have to move that site to our Standard Edition installation but as the trial period is over we can't open the site in any way (even with SharePoint Designer). I tried entering a standard edition key but the beta doesn't accept the key as valid. How should I move the site? By moving the content database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was explicitly stated by MicroSoft (at the time of the beta) that there would be no way to 'upgrade' from the beta version to the final release version.

That said, you could try:

- Attach the content database to the new server.
- back-up the old site using stsadmin/powershell and restore in new version
- set back the date of the server (it's a long shot) to gain access to it?

(no i didn't try any of those my self)

Comment: Yes I know there is no way to upgrade, I am just trying to pull out my publishing site. There is no way to connect to the site. SharePoint wants a key and the RTM keys and beta keys are not compatible so the site is locked down!